# There's a way to set up the default character codification for a defined web page in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I know that I can change it, but it doesn't last, I need set to Occidental and when I re open the navigator is set again to Unicode.

Comment: What version of Firefox, and what language are you trying to keep as default (there is no "Occidental" in recent versions). Also, any web sites or specific one(s)?

Comment: @user3169 42.0 in Spanish Ver->Codificacion de texto->Occidental. In English maybe is View->Text encoding->Western

Comment: Nowadays most websites use Unicode (UTF-8) encoding, so this is hard to check without a web page using a different encoding. If you check the web page source code (Ctrl+U) you will usually see a line like "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />". If UTF-8, there is no need to change the encoding. If a different charset, Firefox should detect and change automatically. If not defined, it will default to the settings in Options --> Content - Fonts - Advanced. I don't know a non UTF-8 site at the moment, but if you add one or two to your question I can test it.

Comment: My PC is in Spanish so I don't know if you are going to the same as me. The weird thing is that in the FF web page info says UTF-8 but also say it haves 2 meta tags an one of them says charset=iso-8859-1. I see that the acute vocals are represented with a '?' by default, and if I manually set to Occidental' encoding the acute vocals are fine but some special character like µ have a square before the µ character.

Comment: @user3169 The page is CCS Forum http://www.ccsinfo.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=1

Comment: According to [Localizations and character encodings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Localizations_and_character_encodings) on MDN, default character set could not be set in config starting in Firefox 28, and is now set according to the Firefox locale of the version installed. So, did you install the Spanish localized version of Firefox (es-ES, es-AR, es-MX, or es-CL)?

Comment: Then I checked this site [Isle of Pines](http://www.isle-of-pines.com/) with same encoding, and Firefox sets automatically to Western (on en-US Firefox). Does it work for you? In any case, the Firefox setting should follow the web page encoding. Your example web site does not work though.

Comment: Yes is es-ES or es-AR, I'm not sure which one. Isle of Pines web page info says Windows-1252 and in meta tag iso-8859 and works ok for me, I can see the acute vocals. The CCS forum web page uses UTF-8/iso-8859-1, is no the same encoding. The only encoding that is the same is in the meta tags, both are iso-8859-1, but your suggested web page is Windows-1252 vs UTF-8.

Comment: So Firefox is using the page Text Encoding to decide its setting, not the meta tag. Windows-1252 is the same as iso-8859-1 (as mentioned in the linked article), so Isle of Pines works correctly. But Text Encoding and meta tag do not match on your site. So it seems to be a problem with that website.

Comment: @user3169 And there's no way to force the character encoding just for that web page? I mean always by default. I don't wan to set it every time I open that web page.

Comment: Not that I know of, since there is no preference to set the default differently. You could ask the site technical support why this is. I am not a server IT guy, but it seems strange that the server is UTF-8 but the text they are pulling from a database is Western.